# An inequality of the coefficients of polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the integer ring. $m = 2^n$ is a power of 2. $\zeta_m$ is the m-primitive root in $\mathbb{C}$. Assume $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\deg f< \phi(m)$, and $N=\phi(m) = m/2$. Write

$$f(X) = a_{N-1} X^{N-1} + \dots + a_0.$$

Denote $||f||_{\infty} = \max_i \{|a_i|\}$ and $||f||^{can}_{\infty} = \max_{gcd(i,2)=1} \{|f(\zeta_m^i)|\}$. Prove that $||f||_{\infty} \leq ||f||^{can}_{\infty}$.

I have tried the case for $f$ being a monomial and know Maximum Modulus Principle. I also reduce the problem to the case $f(0) \leq ||f||^{can}_{\infty}$. Below is my proof.

The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(X) = X^N+1$. We can consider the problem in $Z[X]/(\Phi_m(X))$. Since $|\zeta_m| = 1$,  $||Xf(X)||_{\infty}^{can} = ||f(X)||_{\infty}^{can}$. But the constant term of $Xf(X) \mod \Phi_m(X)$ is $-a_{N-1}$. The other coefficient can be moved similarly to the constant term .

Comment: What is the average of the $f(\zeta_m^j x)$?

Comment: Based on the average, I have tried an answer. Thank @Conrad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reduce to $|f(0)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}^{can}$.

The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_m(X) = X^N+1$. We can consider the problem in $Z[X]/(\Phi_m(X))$. Since $|\zeta_m| = 1$,  $||Xf(X)||_{\infty}^{can} = ||f(X)||_{\infty}^{can}$. But the constant term of $Xf(X) \mod \Phi_m(X)$ is $-a_{N-1}$. The other coefficient can be moved similarly to the constant term .

2. Prove $|f(0)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}^{can}$.

Since $X^N+1 = (X-\zeta_m)(X-\zeta_m^3)\dots$, the elementary symmetric functions of the m-primitive roots are zero except $1 = \zeta_m \zeta_m^3 \dots$ The same holds for $m/2$-primitive roots, $m/4$-primitive roots,$\dots$ Then
$$
\sum_{gcd(m,i)=1} f(\zeta_m^i) = N a_0 .
$$
Therefore, $|f(0)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}^{can}$.